# Why does this book say var is block scoped variable?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

This is from [O'Reilly's Learning JavaScript Design Patterns (by Addy Osmani)](https://www.patterns.dev/posts/classic-design-patterns/#writingdesignpatterns). The below is what author says about `var`, `let` and `const`.

> The difference between `var`, `const` and `let` is that `var` is a
> block-scoped variable, `const` is a block-scoped constant and `let` is a
> block-scoped variable that is only accessible within the block it is
> declared in. Often, you will want to use let but if you want to avoid
> variable assignment, you can use `const` instead. Ultimately, use the
> convention already in the codebase you're using.

I don't understand how can he say `var` is block scoped? If my understanding is right, block is the pair of parentheses. And the scope of var should be the current execution.

Comment: [The var statement declares a function-scoped or globally-scoped variable, optionally initializing it to a value.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Thanks, but this doesn't answer what I have asked. My question is how can he claim that it is block-scoped.

Comment: i don't know this book, opinion based ?!

Comment: It's a typo which has not been detected before publishing.

Comment: @Teemu that is what makes sense to me. I've tweeted to him, let's see if he replies here or there. :)

Comment: Here's the correction I suggested:

 The difference between `var` and `const`/`let` is that `var` is a function-scoped variable (usable in the current function), and `const`/`let` is a block-scoped variable (usable only in the current block). Additionally, the difference between `const` and `let` is that `const` represents a constant that cannot be reassigned, while `let` has the same semantic meaning as `var` (but with a different scope). Often, you will want to use `let` but if you want to avoid variable reassignment, you can use `const` instead.